# ClamAV on CentOS 7 - scan.conf or clamd.conf

Tags: centos, clamav

I've just tried to configure ClamAv on a CentOS 7 set-up. I managed to get it to work albeit with a rodeo-trick.

I would like to know why there are two differently named configuration files within ClamAV on Linux: some set-ups mention /etc/clamd.d/scan.conf as in the case for CentOS, and for others its called /etc/clamd.d/clamd.conf - both are identical?

On this set-up running clamconf reports that "clamd.conf not found" and "clamav-milter.conf not found"

But I find this alarming:

```
Database information
--------------------
Database directory: /var/lib/clamav
WARNING: freshclam.conf and clamd.conf point to different database directories
```

Cheers,

Gustav